# Descompilar um Executavel

Tags: compilação, programação-funcional, engenharia-reversa, descompilação

Criando um programa me surgiu uma curiosidade e gostaria de saber alguns pontos iniciais para eu conseguir concluir minha curiosidade.

Eu criei um aplicativo executável que tenho uma tela de login e senha para utilização do mesmo e fiquei pensando em como funcionaria a engenharia reversa disso.

Basicamente gostaria de saber como através apenas deste executável (sem saber nem a linguagem de programação) eu poderia obter o código deste programa para burlar o login e senha.

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Só em um software muito ruim você conseguira fazer isto. Só pessoas muito ingênuas deixaram algo tão inseguro.

Comment: Nesse caso, seria mais facil alguem fazer uma engenharia reversa pra criar um crack ao login e senha do que tentar obter o código?

Answer (score -2):

Você poderia tentar usar um **disassembler**, que nada mais é que desmonta o binário para linguagem `assembly`(**ASM**), é uma linguagem de baixo nível,uma etapa antes da linguagem de máquina (binário).

Para entender melhor, toda linguagem de programação, seja ela compilada(Java,C) ou interpretada(JS,PHP) passa por um processo de compactação/assimilação que nada mais é a linguagem assembly (por isso tem esse nome, de montagem, assimilação, compactação).

Assim, cada comando em **ASM** tem uma representação em hexadecimal, então podem ser convertidos em hexadecimal e posteriormente binário (de hex para binário é apenas um calculo matemático simples).

E é assim que esses programas "**disassemblers**" faz a engenharia reversa,
binário -> hexadecimal -> linguagem assembly.

**ASM** não é bicho de outro mundo, se você conseguir dominar, você consegue modificar qualquer app/jogo/sistema. é assim que muitos "trainers", "cracks", "hacks", "mods" são feitos quando não temos o código fonte.

Curiosidade extra: é assim que aqueles programas como "Cheat Engine" funciona, assim como **Gameshark** ou **Game Genie** funcionavam nos video games, reparem que trabalham com códigos hexadecimais.

Procure videos sobre **engenharia reversa** no Youtube ou Google, existe muitos!

Comment: não entendi o porque de terem negativado aqui, conhecimento profundo sobre como realmente uma CPU funciona é crime...